# Exception Handling Priority

Tags: java

I am preparing for a midterm that includes exception handling and am stumped why the following code outputs: here 2, here i am, here A. It appears that they are trying to access a valid point within the array list created in the try block, why would it throw an indexoutofbounds exception?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MExceptionMulti {
public void method1 () 
{           
    try {
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList(10);
        l.get(1);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println ("here 1");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println ("here 2");
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println ("here I am");
    }
    System.out.println ("here 4");
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    MExceptionMulti example = new MExceptionMulti();

    try {
        example.method1();
        example.method2();
        System.out.println ("I am after the method");
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println ("here A");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
//      catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println ("here B1");
//      }
//      catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println ("here B2");
//      }
//      catch (Throwable e) {
//          System.out.println ("here B3");
//      }
    System.out.println ("Here at the end of it all!!!");
}





public void method2 () throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println ("How much do you weight?");
    String inputit="";  

    inputit = in.readLine();
    int weight = Integer.parseInt(inputit);

}
```

}

*Edited Code*

Results in:
here 1
here I am
here 4
How much do you weight?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MExceptionMulti {
    public void method1 () 
    {           
        try {
            ArrayList l = new ArrayList(10);
            l.get(1);
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println ("here 1");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("here 2");
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println ("here I am");
        }
        System.out.println ("here 4");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        MExceptionMulti example = new MExceptionMulti();

        try {
            example.method1();
            example.method2();
            System.out.println ("I am after the method");
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println ("here A");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
//      catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println ("here B1");
//          }
//          catch (Exception e) {
//              System.out.println ("here B2");
//          }
//          catch (Throwable e) {
//              System.out.println ("here B3");
//          }
        System.out.println ("Here at the end of it all!!!");
    }





    public void method2 () throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println ("How much do you weight?");
        String inputit="";  

        inputit = in.readLine();
        int weight = Integer.parseInt(inputit);

    }

}
```

Comment: `new ArrayList(10)`, just species the initially reserved size of the arraylist. it doesn't create 10 elements (it is an optimization). Also, please do not use raw types

Comment: I guess i don't understand why it would throw an IndexOutOfBounds Exception even though the element has not been created. If the array of 10 has been created, is there not technically a value assigned to that reserved size such as null?

Comment: It has not been created.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Object> l = new ArrayList(10);
```

The integer argument to this constructor is basically a hint to the implementation to go ahead and internally allocate enough space for ten objects. It still returns an "empty" array list. You'll need to use `l.add(...)` to add elements to it before accessing those elements.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a misconception of how `ArrayList` initialization works. The assignment of `ArrayList l = new ArrayList(10);` will only create the `ArrayList` and reserve the memory slots for `10` elements, but will not populate those slots in any way. Not even with `null`.

Therefore:

1. On `example.method1();`, your `ArrayList` is instantiated with `10` slots on the `ArrayList l = new ArrayList(10);` command, and then you imediatelly try to `get` the element at index `1`.
2. The `ArrayList` is empty. It does not contain any elements, making the index of `1` fall `OutOfBounds`, thus triggering an `OutOfBoundsException`, which is handled in your general `Exception` catch block.
3. Your `Catch` block for this `Exception` prints the `here 2` text to console, and upon falling out of that block's scope, the program transitions to the `finally` block.
4. Your `finally` block prints `here I am`, and when the block fall out of scope, so does the method, thus returning to `main` with an `OutOfBoundsException`.
5. Your main catches the exception and prints `here A`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, Thank you for the explanation 

.

Comment: Why does the line within the try catch not print "here 4"? I tried changing the  Null Pointer Exception on the first catch to a IndexOutOfBounds and it printed the "here4"?

Comment: @DieselGV Is that all you've changed? It should have printed `here 1` and `here I am`.

Comment: yes that is all that I changed. I added the edited code above.

Comment: @DieselGV Oh, so it did print `Here 1` and `here I am`... Should ahve told that from the beginning! =) --- The `here 4` and no `here A` is because the first catch block doesn't have (thus doesn't propagate) any `throws` (exceptions), and thus, instead of falling out of scope after the `finally` block, the method continues onto the `here 4` print command. --- After that, since there is no exception, the catch n `main` doesn't get triggered (because no exceptions were propagated out of `method1` into it), and thus doesn't print `here A`.

Comment: About why the method continues onto the `here 4` print unlike before, remember: Throws behaves like a `return -> exception`... They end the scope of the method (with exception to `finally` blocks, which are *always* run before exiting the `try-catch` scope, regardless of `throws`, `returns` or lack thereof).